# .conf file RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, config

I have a generated apache .conf file that looks like the code below. The last step to enable .conf file is to run a2ensite aaaaaaa.conf, which throws me an error:

> RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters.

I don't understand that error. There are no flags. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with that code?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin postmaster@aaaaaaa.aa
        ServerName aaaaaaa.aa

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/aaaaaaa.aa/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/aaaaaaa.aa/access.log combined

        DocumentRoot /var/www/aaaaaaa.aa
        <Directory "/var/www/html/aaaaaaa.aa">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = aaaaaaa.aa
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the space between **= aaaaaaa.aa**
This is correct:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =aaaaaaa.aa
```